# How to get checkbox value onclick submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

In this code, I have multiple checkboxes i.e. `name="recruiter_id"` with multiple submit button. Now, What happens when I click on the first row submit button it alert data but when I click on the last row submit button then it shows wrong `recruiter_id` I don't know why? So, How can I get different `recruiter_id` `onclick` different submit button? Please help me.

```
<?php
    foreach($wishlist as $row)
    {
?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="recruiter_id" value="<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>" class="recruiter_id">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".job_id").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            job_id = this.id;
            recruiter_id = $("input[name='recruiter_id']:checked").val();
            alert(job_id);
            alert(recruiter_id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: first of all, your submit button must be outside of for loop. and you can     `foreach($wishlist as $k => $row)` and `name="recruiter_id<?php echo $k; ?>"` `$("input[name^='recruiter_id']:checked")` should do the trick

Comment: Go up to the parent `tr` first (via jQuery’s `.parents()`, and then find the checkbox input inside of that.

Comment: Do you want all checked recruiter_id while you click on assign button? why do you have more submit button? can you please explain more in your question?

Comment: Sir, Please take look one time I had try to explain more @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the type of input to `button` instead of submit :

```
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>" data-val="<?php echo $row['rid']?>" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
```

Then inside the click event go up to the parent `tr` and check id the related checkbox is checked using `.closest()` and `:checked` like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".job_id").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var job_id = this.id;
    var recruiter_id = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='recruiter_id']:checked").val();

    console.log('job ID : ' + job_id + ' --- Recruiter ID:' + recruiter_id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="recruiter_id" value="1" class="recruiter_id">1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="1" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="recruiter_id" value="2" class="recruiter_id">2
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="2" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="recruiter_id" value="3" class="recruiter_id">3
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="3" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
<?php
foreach($wishlist as $row)
  {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="recruiter_id" value="<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>" class="recruiter_id">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="<?php echo $row['job_id']; ?>" data-val="<?php echo $row['rid']?>" class="btn btn-danger job_id" value="Assign" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".job_id").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        job_id = this.id;
        recruiter_id = $(this).data("val");
        //$("input[name='recruiter_id']:checked").val();
        alert(job_id);
        alert(recruiter_id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try document.getElementById("#yourid of checkbox").val() it will give u the value